# UPDATE a field in one table with the SUM of another

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, sql-update

I'm trying to set the value of a field in a table to the SUM of another set of fields in another table by:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET fieldToUpdate = 
(
    SELECT SUM(fieldToSum) FROM table2
) 
WHERE thirdField = 'A'
```

but I'm not having any luck. I've seen a lot of examples that use joins, but my 2 tables aren't related in any way.

Thanks

Comment: Or what error are you getting? In other words, what does "not having any luck" mean?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It's just not updating the value from its previous value (which is NULL).

Comment: What is the data type of `fieldToUpdate`?

Comment: If it's still `NULL` then the explanation is simple - you're not updating the right rows, or you're not updating the rows you think you are.

Comment: Wait, your table has `NULL` in the `fieldToUpdate` column, and you expect your `UPDATE` to affect rows, even though your `WHERE` clause says to affect rows where the value is `A`? Why do you think this should work? `NULL` and `'A'` are not the same thing. I suspect maybe you meant `WHERE fieldToUpdate IS NULL`.

Comment: Sorry. I typed my initial question incorrectly. The `WHERE fieldToUpdate` should have read: `WHERE thirdField = 'A'`. I've updated my initial question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It turned out I was trying to update the field to a value that exceeded the width I had defined on `fieldToUpdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment above, I was attempting to update `fieldToUpdate` with a value that exceeded the width of that column. Thanks for everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 4):

While the subquery should work, you could break it up like this:

```
DECLARE @s INT;

SELECT @s = SUM(fieldToSum) FROM dbo.table2;

UPDATE dbo.table1
SET fieldToUpdate = @s
WHERE fieldToUpdate = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1):

As your tables are not related, it looks like what you have already written should work. All rows in table1 with fieldToUpdate = 'A' will have the fieldToUpdate's column set to the sum of  all fieldToSum's in table2. Maybe you can clarify your question for a better answer? As in, what exactly is the problem you are getting or a sample dataset and results expected

UPDATE:

Based on your new comments, if the previous value is NULL, then doing something like `fieldToUpdate = [ANY VALUE]` will result in no rows being returned. You would need to use `fieldToUpdate IS NULL`. Or, you could keep the = if you do something like this: `ISNULL(fieldToUpdate, 'A') = 'A'`.

Last, as a debugging measure, you can check `@@ROWCOUNT` after your update to see if it is even updating anything (which would affirm the need for IS NULL).

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect possibilities based on your comments

Comment: Justin - I corrected my original question. I was referencing an incorrect column name in my initial question (though not in my original code). My comment below is the final answer to my issue. Thanks for your help.